# Select Query With Variable

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I'm working withing Oracle 6i Form
the form is search form , it has many text items for criteria search
and there is command button
when pressed , the form will show all records
is user selected some items in creteria text items , the result will be filtered
based on those creteria
now this is done , and then I want to export the result to a text file using the following code

```
OUTFILE TEXT_IO.FILE_TYPE;
filename  varchar2(100);
sql_string varchar2(8000);
a number(10);
begin
    a := 0;

  if :norm.Dob_fr is not null and :norm.Dob_to is not null then
sql_string :=  sql_string || ' (DATE_FROM >= to_date(''' || to_char(:norm.Dob_fr,'YYYY-MM-DD') || ''',''YYYY-MM-DD'') and date_to <= to_date(''' || to_char(:norm.Dob_to,'YYYY-MM-DD') || ''',''YYYY-MM-DD'')';
 a := 1;
  end if;


if  :norm.per_fr is not null and :norm.per_to is not null then
    if a = 1 then
        sql_where := ' and ';
    else
        sql_where := ' ( ';
        a := 1;
    end if;
    sql_string :=  sql_string || sql_where || ' pay_date >= to_date(''' || to_char(:norm.per_fr,'YYYY-MM-DD') || ''',''YYYY-MM-DD'') and pay_date <= to_date(''' || to_char(:norm.per_to,'YYYY-MM-DD') || ''',''YYYY-MM-DD'')';

end if; 

       sql_string :=  sql_string  || ' ) ';  
FOR SE IN ('select * from V_BILL_TRAN where ' || nvl(sql_string,'1=1') loop
```

the export code is working well , but my issue is in the last statement shown above , the where statement "sql_string: it may or not contain a data
then the code is not accepted by oracle form 6i
there is something wrong

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
sql_string :=  sql_string  || ' ) ';
```

The closing bracket causes problems because - even if there's nothing in `sql_string`, after concatenating the bracket, `sql_string` will become `)` and it'll cause problems in the next statement (`FOR` loop) as `nvl(sql_string, 1=1)` won't take effect - the result will be

```
select * from V_BILL_TRAN where )
```

instead of

```
select * from V_BILL_TRAN where 1=1
```

Rewrite it to

```
sql_string := sql_string || case when sql_string is not null then ')' end;
```

Comment: Hello , i already changed the statement as you advised , and it gives me compiling error at word "case"  Error 103 , encountered the symbol case when expecting one of the following

Comment: It is difficult to debug code you can't see. Edit the initial message you posted by adding your last code version.

Answer (score 0):

this is the initial code

```
OUTFILE TEXT_IO.FILE_TYPE;
filename  varchar2(100);
sql_string varchar2(8000);
a number(10);
begin
    a := 0;

  if :norm.Dob_fr is not null and :norm.Dob_to is not null then
sql_string :=  sql_string || ' (DATE_FROM >= to_date(''' || to_char(:norm.Dob_fr,'YYYY-MM-DD') || ''',''YYYY-MM-DD'') and date_to <= to_date(''' || to_char(:norm.Dob_to,'YYYY-MM-DD') || ''',''YYYY-MM-DD'')';
 a := 1;
  end if;


if  :norm.per_fr is not null and :norm.per_to is not null then
    if a = 1 then
        sql_where := ' and ';
    else
        sql_where := ' ( ';
        a := 1;
    end if;
    sql_string :=  sql_string || sql_where || ' pay_date >= to_date(''' || to_char(:norm.per_fr,'YYYY-MM-DD') || ''',''YYYY-MM-DD'') and pay_date <= to_date(''' || to_char(:norm.per_to,'YYYY-MM-DD') || ''',''YYYY-MM-DD'')';

end if; 

       sql_string :=  sql_string  || ' ) ';  
FOR SE IN ('select * from V_BILL_TRAN where ' || nvl(sql_string,'1=1') loop
```